Generating Xpath to get attribute value via IMPORTXML
I'm accessing this website: https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/search/mail%20merge
and I'm trying to identify the value of the data-card-index attribute of a div that contains the href: ./marketplace/app/mailmeteor/1008170693301.
Upon research, I saw this IMPORTXML function and I believe this is the solution, but somehow can't develop the XPATH properly (even with the Copy > Xpath approach).
I saw this and this among others, but it seems you'll need to have some good level of HTML knowhow to work this out. Anyone who can provide guidance on this please?
Here are some things I tried that didn't work:

=IMPORTXML("https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/search/mail%20merge","//a/@href")
=IMPORTXML("https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/search/mail%20merge","//div[contains(@href='./marketplace/app/mailmeteor/1008170693301)]//@*'")


You have a webpage that is HTML.  You are trying to scrape the HTML to get a value of the data-card-index.  You cannot use ImportXML on a HTML page.  HTML and XML are similar but the same tool in most cases will not work.  You need to use a HTML parser to get the value

Hi @jdweng I thought I was doing similar to this wherein the user was trying to extract a value within the HTML. Or are they entirely different?

Your webpage is not xml, it is html.

This page uses neither XML nor HTML. The content is populated dynamically using javascript. IMPORTXML and IMPORTHTML will not work here.

Does this answer your question? Scraping data to Google Sheets from a website that uses JavaScript
